# Wrong proof for Slutsky's theorem $Z_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} a, Y_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} Y \Rightarrow Z_n+Y_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} a+Y$

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $Z_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} a, Y_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} Y$. Show
> $$Z_n+Y_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} a+Y$$

My wrong attemp:
From $Z_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} a$ we get $\varphi _{Z_n} \rightarrow \varphi _a$
From $Y_n \overset{d}{\rightarrow} Y$ we get $\varphi _{Y_n} \rightarrow \varphi _Y$
And so

$$\varphi _{Y_n+Z_n}= \varphi _{Y_n} \varphi _{Z_n} \rightarrow \varphi _a \varphi _Y=\varphi _{a+Y}$$

And if CF are point wise converge then the $\varphi$ it converge to is the CF of the limit r.v.

And so I get $\lim Y_n+Z_n =a+Y$

Can you help me find my error?

Thank you,

Comment: And so I get $\lim_d Y_nZ_n = aY$, your work doesn't show this at all, not sure where this conclusion came from. The other issue is that you are assuming independence, which is not needed.

Comment: I used the theorem at the end: 
 if $\varphi _n$ converges point wise to $\varphi$ which is continouse at 0, then $\mu _n$ is tight and there exsist a probability messure $\mu$ s.t $\mu _n \Rightarrow \mu$ and $\varphi$ is its cf.

You are right that I used $Y_n, Z_n$ are i.i.d, thank you. But im wondering if there is another reason this proof is not correct. I'm I miss understand the therom

Comment: Your proof is OK if you assume independence, though as remarked before, I don't know where you got $\lim_d Y_nZ_n = aY$ from. Maybe you meant to write $\lim_d Y_n+Z_n = Y+a$

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake. I corrected it